# Facebook app not requesting user_photos permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

I'm working on a Facebook app which needs to get the user's photos. In the app dashboard, I have added user_photos to the 'User & Friend Permissions' field under the 'Permissions' section.

When I click 'Preview Login Dialog', it shows that the app will get 'Your basic info' and 'Your photos', but when I go to test the app and get the authorization dialog it says the app will get 'Your basic info' and 'Your email address'.

I have tried removing the app through my Facebook account settings (Apps) and then going back to the app, but the permissions are still incorrect. I have also had a friend test this on his computer and he's getting the same result.

The app is set up as 'App on Facebook' under 'Basic' settings. Am I missing something somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the fact, that the permissions you enter in the "permissions" sections are only used within authenticated referrals. (un)fortunately, this functionality is going to be removed with the february breaking changes. have a look here: http://die.socialisten.at/2012/10/passive-sharing-the-end-of-authenticated-referrals-advanced-open-graph-2/

So, to put it in a nutshell: your app itself should be prompting the user this extended permission. you have to change the scope parameter of your login dialog url.

Comment: Thanks, Johannes. The plan was to move over to an app-based permissions model eventually, so this will probably end up putting me ahead of the game.

Comment: Those breaking changes that you linked to are almost 2 years old.  The new FB developer console doesn't even have those options anymore.